# post a map from JSP to action

Tags: jsp, struts2

Inside my action I have a map that will be sent to JSP

```
Map<String,Person> map = LinkedHashMap<String,Person>();
map.put("1",personA);
map.put("2",personB);
map.put("3",personC);
```

Well, I can render the JSP with the values in the map properly, but I am struggling to find a solution that will allow me to get back the map into another action. Here is what I tried:

```
<s:iterator value="map" status="p"> 
   <s:hidden name="map.[%{#p.index}].key"/>
   <s:hidden name="map.[%{#p.index}].value.name"/>
   <s:hidden name="map.[%{#p.index}].value.address"/>
</s:iterator>
```

And I keep getting the concurrent modification exception.

Anybody had a clue? Thanks a lot!!

Comment: Put the map into session.

Comment: Why put the map in session? And how would that solve the syntax problem?

Comment: Where the concurrent modification exception happening?

Comment: after the jsp in rendered

Answer (score 2):

1. You don't need key and value, they're automatically handled;
2. The key part is syntactically wrong: remove the dot (or the square brackets);
3. The key part is missing the double quotes; your syntax is to access a List;
4. Your LinkedHashMap is using a sequential number as key; why not using a List then ?

By the way, totally untested but It should be

```
<s:iterator value="map" status="p"> 
   <s:hidden name="map['%{#p.index}'].name"/>
   <s:hidden name="map['%{#p.index}'].address"/>
</s:iterator>
```

That in Java is something like

```
   ((Person)getMap().get("1")).setName();
   ((Person)getMap().get("1")).setAddress();
```

assuming they're consecutive, ordered etc. But this solution doesn't seem reliable to me...

Comment: same concurrent modification exception